# Is it possible that Woocommerce category should not delete if it has product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible that Woocommerce category should not delete if it has product. I am facing this issue and I know it can possible but how this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No There is no option like you are asking we need to create by doing custom code because in backend if you go and press delete button on category it will deleted you need to add php code to restrict that if this category has product not allow to delete...